# Как с помощью logging писать в логер только DEBUG-сообщения без сообщений более высокого уровня?

Tags: python, логирование

Использую стандартную библиотеку `logging` и мне нужно выводить в лог сообщения уровня `DEBUG`. Но как известно, что при стандартной настройке в лог также будут записаны сообщения уровней `INFO`, `ERROR`, `CRITICAL` и `WARNING`. А это не то что мне не нужно. Мне нужно оставить только и только 'DEBUG`.

Как это осуществить?

Спросив у старины Гугла увидел одно из решений на SO: [Python logging: display only information from debug level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108973/python-logging-display-only-information-from-debug-level). Но мне кажется должно быть решение проще.

Есть ли оно? Более простое решение?

*UPD*
Видеть только и только отладочные сообщения мне нужно в процессе разработки. Расставлять по коду print()-конструкции пишущие в debug-лог, мне как-то не хочется. Но во время отладки мне интересно только лишь конкретные факты о работе алгоритма, но вместо этого получаю в довесок и "Вася зашел с IP..." или "Вася получил токен...." или "Скоро не хватит местана диске..." и др. сообщения, которые важны,но не сейчас. Не в момен разработки!

Именно по этой причине и хочется писать в лог только и только debug-сообщения. Сейчас я это делаю с помощью grep, но много кратное его повторение как-то уже поднадоело ;(

Comment: Дело в том, что в этой библиотеке уровень детализированности лога работает «от сюда и ниже»: DEBUG > INFO > WARNING > ERROR > CRITICAL.

Решение по ссылке является вполне себе «простым» и более того архитектурно правильным.


Скорее всего вы используете логгер не для тех целей. Возможно вы можете пояснить свою задачу?

Answer (score 1):

Согласен с @maxwell, в ответе приведено рабочее решение. Есть еще один штатный способ https://stackoverflow.com/a/879937/4249707 Если сложность оценивать в количестве строк кода, то можно сказать, что он проще :)

Comment: Да, но @maxwell написал в виде комментария, а не ответа! ;)